# Get the rows from previous month

Tags: mysql

I am trying this query

```
SELECT *
FROM flexible_products
WHERE YEAR(updated_at) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
AND MONTH(updated_at) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
```

for my current work. What I want to do is to get all rows from the previous month,

Like for example, we have today July 04, 2017, I would like to get rows from January to June, which is not the outcome of the above query.

What is the best way to this in MySQL?

Comment: Should the records always be between Jan and current-1 month?

Comment: update_at is column name ?

Comment: I should meet the previous month idea

Comment: @Ravindra yes that is date column

Comment: you ask 2 different things: records from previous month (1st June unti 30th June) or you ask all from this year until start current month: (1st January until 30th June) . What is it?

Comment: @IvoP Any month previous from the current month and year we have for example, but should be applicable if the year will be the coming year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return all records updated on or after January 1 of the current year but stictly before the first of the current month.

```
SELECT *
FROM flexible_products
WHERE updated_at >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') AND
      updated_at < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

You should also try this or you can get data between any two dates.

SELECT * FROM flexible_products WHERE updated_at BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -3 MONTH) AND NOW( )

date output is:-
DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -3 MONTH) //2017-04-01
NOW( ) //2017-07-04 11:17:38

Answer (score 0):

a bit shorter. Not sure if also faster

```
SELECT *
FROM flexible_products
WHERE 
  YEAR(updated_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND
  MONTH(updated_at) < MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you correctly you can do this

```
WHERE updated_at <= '2017-07-01' AND updated_at >= '2017-01-01'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, because your query is correct as of this moment.  But your query would fail as soon as August 1 comes around.